# How to compare date strings in the format yyyy-mm-dd in PHP

Tags: php

I have a range of dates in string format in the form of

```
'2014-10-12'
```

what i want to do is compare these dates so i can get the oldest and the youngest.

In PHP how do i convert these to a format where i can do the following?

```
$oldestdate;
$youngesdate;

//loop though all the dates
if($exampledate < $youngesdate)
    $youesdate = $exampledate;

if($exampledate > $oldestdate)
    $oldestdate = $exampledate;
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the `strtotime()` function [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.)

Comment: I'm certain someone told me that dosnt work on dates older than 1970, will give it a try though thansk

Comment: You can also use a simple string compare for that (if the format won't change).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nice thing about YYYY-MM-DD style dates is that they will always sort correctly, whether treated as text (as in your example), numbers (e.g. 20141012), or actual dates.

Thus, there's no need to do anything special to compare them as long as everything is the same format.  Your code, as written, should work as-is (besides the typos for $youngestdate).

Note that if you want to do anything besides comparing them -- e.g. anything actually involving treating them like actual dates -- you will indeed want something like strtotime() or a mix of mktime() + substr()

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `strotime`? reference http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

then you can easily compare with `<`and `>` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checkdate(12, 31, 2000)? [PHP.net Checkdate function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

> For years between 1 and 32767 inclusive.Check post 2 in the php.net link

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime class.

```
$arr = ['2012-10-12', '2004-10-12', '2014-08-12', '2014-09-12', '2014-09-13', '2014-09-11'];

$_now = new DateTime('now');

foreach ( $arr as $_t ) {

    $d = new DateTime ( $_t );

    if ( !isset($newest) || $d >= $newest ) $newest = $d;

    if ( !isset($oldest ) || $d <= $oldest ) $oldest = $d;    

}    

echo 'Newest ' . $newest->format('Y-m-d');
echo 'Oldest' . $oldest->format('Y-m-d');
```

Take a look here: [Reference on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetimeinterface.php)

And here is an [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/434b6ab35791b2810c62c6fda4f433ef891dfe6f)